# GitHub user to be the committer when I do a local commit?

Tags: git, github

This is a bit weird. I am cloning GitHub repos locally. Then I do local committs.

User:
When I push those changes I can't get the user right. What I want is my GitHub user (noopman) to be the committer. Instead I get all sorts of strange users.

Password:
Also when I do push to a repo that I own it does not ask me for the password each time. What did I set to get the password stored and how can a I reset that?

I have edited my .gitconfig and tried different combinations of user.name and user.email.

Here is the repo I am trying to commit to currently - notice all my test commits
[with different users](http://github.com/noopman/fluent-management/commits/master)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to
[set up Git](http://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)

```sh
# Sets the default name for git to use when you commit
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"

# Sets the default email for git to use when you commit
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

[and SSH](http://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

```sh
# Creates a new ssh key using the provided email
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Comment: And make sure GitHub knows about that email address being tied to your user.  Go to Account Settings -> Email Settings and make sure the email address you're using is in there.

Comment: FYI, the bit on SSH is unnecessary.  GitHub ignores that.  It's only the key itself that matters.