# MsysGit git-cmd.bat CLI: How do I specify my public key

Tags: git, authentication, msysgit

Let me start by stating the obvious ... my confidence with git is still cowering off in a dark corner :)
We've been using it here in-house lately, and I'm ***starting*** to get the hang of it, but I've got a few more hours to put in before I get my license ;)

We have a repository within our intranet, and when using the git-cmd cli, git looks for the default key in the default location when trying to authenticate.
Our repository is using a different key.

Is there a git config file or something that I can edit to put in the path to the proper key?
How do I set the credentials?

Comment: Do you use a key agent to store your private keys? Like pageant?

Comment: I didn't realize it at the time at the time of asking the Q, but yeah. TortoiseGIT had an instance of pageant running, so plink was able to just hook into that as soon as I got my GIT_SSH env var correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

If you are accessing the repository over HTTPS, then you can use the `http.sslKey` configuration or the `GIT_SSL_KEY` environment variable to specify its location [(see the git config docs)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

**Long answer**

Usually it doesn't matter where your private keys are, because ideally they are stored in a key agent, and what you need to figure out is how to make Git use the key agent.

(The thing is, ideally a private should have a passphrase, and so re-entering it every time would not be practical. The key agent is to simplify this.)

Since everyone should be using private keys protected by a passphrase, and thus a key agent to make that practical, it is not common to have to configure the location of the key file.

In windows I use `pageant` as the key agent, which is part of the [PuTTY tools](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Simply run `pageant.exe` and add your private key. Next, to make Git use `pageant` to get your private key, you need to set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to point to `plink.exe`, for example `/c/path/to/putty/plink.exe`. You can set it like this in your environment variables, even though it uses UNIX-style path separators.

I am not familiar with TortoiseGit, but I *guess* it probably has it's own `plink.exe`, you can use that too. And since you already have TortoiseGit working, I *guess* you might not even need the key agent at all, just set `GIT_SSH`. But these are just guesses. The setup I described with PuTTY and pagent should work, as I use it myself. In any case you *should* use a key agent, and protect your keys with a passphrase, etc etc etc.

Comment: SWEET!! Thanks for all the info.  Sounds great. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, when creating the _GIT_SSH_ Environment Variable in Windows (7), I did need to make sure the path to plink.exe didn't have any spaces, so I symlinked the "Program Files" dir's with [**junction**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx), and I went with the Windows style path separators because it helped me troubleshoot some roadblocks.

Comment: @mOrloff you can escape spaces with backslashes, or you can enclose the value within double quotes. No need to use junction for this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Janos. It was a personal preference because the _"Program Files"_ and _"Program Files (x86)"_ names have bugged me for a long time. I figured it was as good a time as any to get that thorn removed  :)

Answer (score 0):

[Generating SSH Keys](http://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

```sh
# Creates a new ssh key using the provided email
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

[GitHub user to be the committer when I do a local commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15985681/github-user-to-be-the-committer-when-i-do-a-lo)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to generate a key, I need to specify which on e to use.  My TortoiseGit (& WinSCP) authenticate with that server just fine, I just need to get Git to use the right key from the (git-cmd.bat) cli.